# How can I access a property of my class by using isKindOfClass within a for-in loop?

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I need to iterate through `SKNode.children` within a `for-in` loop and I need to check whether a condition is true or false, via the `node`, by accessing a property of my class. I guess I need to cast the `node` as an object of my class in order to be able to access the property of type `bool`, by using the `isKindOfClass` method in Swift. Here is the code for Objective-C. Any idea how to do the same in Swift?

```
-(BOOL)isCompleted() {
    for(SKNode *node in mainLayer.children) {
        if([node isKindOfClass:[Laser class]]) {
            if(!((Laser*)node).indestructible) {
                return NO
            }
        }
    }
    return YES
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly direct translation:

```
var isCompleted: Bool {
    for node in mainLayer.children {
        guard let laser = node as? Laser else { continue }
        if !laser.indestructible {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

More idiomatic:

```
    var isCompleted: Bool {
        return !mainLayer.children.lazy.flatMap { $0 as? Laser }.contains { !$0.indestructible }
    }
```

But the double negation is confusing, so I'd probably add a couple of accessors to clarify it further, like this:

```
class Laser: SKNode {
    var indestructible = false
    final var destructible: Bool { return !indestructible }
}

 class MyScene: SKScene {

    var mainLayer = SKNode()

    var isUncompleted: Bool {
        return mainLayer.children.lazy.flatMap { $0 as? Laser }.contains { $0.destructible }
    }

    final var isCompleted: Bool { return !isUncompleted }

}
```

Or maybe this:

```
    var isCompleted: Bool {
        return mainLayer.children.lazy.flatMap { $0 as? Laser }.filter { $0.destructible }.isEmpty
    }
```

Comment: I think `return (mainLayer.children.filter { $0 is Laser } as! [Laser]).contains { !$0.indestructible }` might be more readable, but obviously that's subjective

Comment: You could also do `children.flatMap { $0 as? Laser }` to avoid the cast.

Comment: I think `as` should be `as?` in your first example and the logic in the second example is incorrect. If you change the 2nd example to `return !(mainLayer.children.contains {!(($0 as? Laser)?.indestructible ?? true)})`, the results are the same as the 1st example.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote the answer on my iPad on the bus so it was hard to get the syntax perfect. I've fixed it up now and checked it in a playground.

Comment: now do a time test and find out which is fastest lol